# Propagation of vectorial electric field with Fourier Optics

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, fourier-transform, polarization, clifford-algebra

In Fourier Optics one can propagate in free space the electric field $E(x,y)$ of a monochromatic light beam along the z-axis by decomposing it into plane waves via the Fourier transform, then multiplying each mode by the transfer function of free space $H(\nu_x,\nu_y,d)$ and finally reversing the Fourier transform. [image: figure 1]

For a simulation of light propagation, I want to apply a similar technique but to a vectorial electric field, $\overrightarrow{E}(x,y)$, for which the polarization depends on the position in the x-y plane. **Is it correct to apply the Fourier transform, multiply by the transfer function of free space, and reverse the Fourier transform component-wise to each polarization direction, or is this making incorrect assumptions?**

I am aware of Vectorial Rayleigh Sommerfeld technique with which one can also propagate polarized light, but for my purposes this technique is unfortunately too slow. I would also appreciate it if anyone knows any other tricks to speed up this computation.

Regarding analogues to the Fourier transform of vector fields, I have explored the Clifford Fourier transform. I'm not sure whether this technique can be used, has anyone used this? Is there any other alternative I'm missing? [J. Ebling and G. Scheuermann, "Clifford Fourier transform on vector fields,"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1432692).